# How to solve Linux symbol lookup error for undefined symbols

Tags: rhel, mysql

There are lots of similar issues on the web related to undefined symbol lookup errors, but none of them explains how to deal with the error.

I am using RHEL7 and I tried to install MySQL-workbench from `mysql-workbench-community-6.3.10-1.el7.x86_64.rpm` package using the `rpm` command.

There were some dependency issues and I tried to resolve them one by one. Several times it caused problems for `python-crypto` and `python2-crypto` `python-paramiko` packages and somehow I got the dependencies resolved. Several times I had to uninstall the python related packages.

Finally, the workbench was installed, but I am stuck with a symbol lookup error which is as follows:

`Found /lib64/libproj.so.0`

`/usr/libexec/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/liblinux_utilities.so.6.3.10: undefined symbol: g_application_add_main_option_entries`

I searched some forums and there are discussions beyond my understanding, though I tried to find some information about it using the `nm` command which I thought would help you experts understand the issue.

````
nm: /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/liblinux_utilities.so.6.3.10: no symbols

[root@MYSQLTEST sqladmin]# nm -A /usr/libexec/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin | grep g_application_add_main_option_entries

nm: /usr/libexec/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin: no symbols

[root@MYSQLTEST sqladmin]# nm -u /usr/libexec/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin | grep g_application_add_main_option_entries

nm: /usr/libexec/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin: no symbols

[root@MYSQLTEST sqladmin]# nm -n /usr/libexec/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin | grep g_application_add_main_option_entries

nm: /usr/libexec/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin: no symbols

root@MYSQLTEST sqladmin]# file /usr/libexec/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin

/usr/libexec/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=0xae7dc55c9352d44d2fe6ef881c4d019211d4c69d, stripped```

Please help me out with how should I go about resolving it. Please if possible provide steps to resolve it. I will be glad to provide if any more info is required.

Thank you.
````

Comment: I would suggest you install with YUM instead of forcing it with RPM, YUM will handle dependencies for you.  Should only require standard repositories and EPEL repository.

Comment: I know :-( but internet access is not allowed on the servers I am working on :-( . I downloaded the rpms on Windows from where using x shell I access the servers and then transferred them to servers.

Comment: ouch, when i installed mysql-workbench i noticed about a hundred dependencies.  I guess you just need to make sure you get them all installed.  Could always host the YUM repositories locally if you need them again, but for just this package it might be a bit much.  No internet is quite a constraint.

Comment: @@GracefulRestart: you mean to use yum --downloadonly --downloaddir options. Is this what you mean by that? Well, that's how I downloaded and saved the packets from test machine and moved them to the UAT. But still is the symbol lookup error solvable?

Comment: You never actually say how you are using the RPM command to install your packages.  My guess is that you are doing something that is missing dependencies.  If you have downloaded all of the packages already, you should be able to run them through YUM to make sure you have everything (using --disablerepo here so it does not error out trying to check internet repositories):  `yum install --disablerepo=* /some/dir/with/required_packages/*.rpm`

Comment: When I installed workbench, I used rpm -ivh workbench-package.rpm, I received errors regarding dependencies, I picked up each dependent package and downloaded it and tried to resolve the dependencies one by one. The packages python-crypto, python2-crypto and python-paramiko were the ones causing a lot of troubles. That is how I tried to resolve the dependencies. Let me give it another try using yum, if I am allowed temporary internet access on the test server. Let's see. I ll uninstall the earlier workbench and reinstall it using yum. Thank you.

Comment: :-( I removed the mysql-workbench using yum remove and reinstalled it using yum install -y mysql-workbench. and  when I try to launch it, I am stuck with the same error as mentioned in the question. I have internet access for a limited period :-(. The symbol lookup error must be resolved.

Comment: Too bad that did not work.  If you are using RHEL you should be asking their support what the issue is or how it should be installed.  I apparently cannot get it to work either, from a fresh CentOS 7 install.  Though I did not have the errors you are seeing, I was able to start the mysql-workbench program but I was having X display issues.

Comment: Well, I m tired too :-(, RHEL support ain't an option. I tried to strip the undefined symbol using linux strip --strip-unndeeded, strip --strip-symbol command, and objcopy -N foo a.so and renamed the symbolic link and so on. Out of gut feeling, I thought the mysql-server may be causing trouble because it's an old version, I removed it and installed the latest mysql-server. Still stuck with the same issue. I ll just drop it. Try fresh on new test server. Maybe because I uninstalled  and reinstalled several python related packages, this is happening.

Comment: I formatted my machine. Tried to reinstall the mysql-workbench-community-6.3.10-1.el7.x86_64.rpm, but same error. I tried installing an older version MySQL Workbench CE (GPL) 6.2.5 0  build 397. It's working fine apart from occasional crash. I don't know if there's issue with the latest version or not.